# Using the $ sign in variables

Tags: assembly

```
DATA SEGMENT
  T DB 0FFH,255,-5,251,'8'
  LEN=$-T
DATA ENDS
```

What does the $ sign means? how it will effect the LEN value, thanks.

Comment: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.4

Comment: What flavor of assembly is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are offsets, they are addresses.  Your T variable is 5 bytes long.  LEN has an address also, what the $ sign does, is during Assembly, takes the address of LEN and subtracts the address of T and that result will equal the length of T. Now, when you need the length of T in your code, you can use LEN, change the value of T?  LEN will reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what flavor of assembly this is (been a long time since I did any and I was only familiar with the Motorola kind), but I would hazard a guess that `$` refers to the current address. So as you create entries inside the segment (using `DB`, which I assume stands for "define byte"), the value of `$` gets updated according to the sizes you are defining. Therefore when you do `$-T`, you're subtracting the address of `T` from `$`, which gives you the size of that segment.